# Cancancan gem usage in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I have a rails application which manages all the registered users. All crud operations can be done on the details of the registered users. I now need to restrict the application in such a way that only the admin user should be allowed to view all the registered users. Any user without the admin privilege should be able to view, edit, and delete his/her post only. I have used devise gem for authentication and plans to use cancancan gem for authorization. I have only a single model class called Users which contains a text attribute (to store "Admin" or "Nonadmin"). Here is my controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!


    def index
        if current_user.role ==  "Admin"
          @users = User.all
        else
          @user = User.find(current_user.id)
       end
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path if current_user.nil?
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
        end
      end

       def show
        if (User.all.pluck(:id).include?params[:id].to_i) == false
          flash[:notice] = "You cannot perform such an action"
        else
         @user = User.find(params[:id])
       end
         respond_to do |format|
            format.html
         end
       end

       def new
        @user = User.new
       end

       def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

       if @user.save
          redirect_to :action => 'index'
       else
          render :action => 'new'
       end
       end

       def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :age, :biography, :email)
       end

       def edit
        if (User.all.pluck(:id).include?params[:id].to_i) == false
          flash[:notice] = "You cannot perform such an action"
        else
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
        end
       end

       def update
        params.inspect
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

       if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @user
       else
          render :action => 'edit'
       end
       end

       def delete
        User.find(params[:id]).destroy
       redirect_to :action => 'index'
       end

    end
```

My user table has the following fields: id,email,first_name,last_name,biography,email,role. It also contains all the devise-related fields.Below is my User model :

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    after_initialize :default_values

      private
        def default_values
          self.role ||= "Non-admin"
        end
end
```

I have hardcoded my admin credentials in seeds.rb as shown below:

if User.find_by(:role => 'Admin').nil?
  User.create([{email:"admin_user@usermanagementsystem.com",password: "topsecret",first_name:"admin",last_name:"ums", biography: "i serve as admin at the ums", age:20, role: "Admin"}])
end

View files:
Index.html.erb:-

```
<table id="albums" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>        NAME        </th>
      <th>        EMAIL       </th>
      <% if current_user.role == "Admin" %>
      <th>        EDIT        </th>
      <th>        SHOW        </th>
      <th>        DESTROY     </th>
      <% end %>
      <th colspan="15"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<% if current_user.role == "Admin" %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', users_edit_path(id: user.id), class: "small button"%></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', users_show_path(id: user.id), class: "small button"%></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', users_delete_path(id: user.id),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } , class: "small button"%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<tr>
    <td><%= @user.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= @user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', users_edit_path(id: @user.id), class: "small button" %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', users_delete_path(id: @user.id),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } , class: "small button"%></td>
  </tr>
<%end %>
</table>

<%#= link_to 'Change password', edit_user_registration_path,  class: "small button" %>
```

edit.html.erb:-

```
<% if @user.nil? == false %>
<%= form_for @user , :as => :user, :url => users_update_path(@user), :method => :PUT do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br>

  <%= f.label :age %>:
  <%= f.number_field :age %><br>

  <%= f.label :biography %>:
  <%= f.text_field :biography %><br>

  <%= f.label :email %>:
  <%= f.text_field :email %><br>

  <%= f.submit :class => 'small button' %>
<% end %>
<%else%>
<h3> Such a user record does not exist. Please click on a specific user </p>
<%end%>
```

show.html.erb

```
<br>
<br>
<% if @user.nil? == false %>
<h3>User details</h3>
<table id="albums" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>FIRSTNAME</th>
      <th>LASTNAME</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
      <th>BIOGRAPHY</th>
      <th>AGE</th>
      <th colspan="20"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= @user.first_name %> </td>
    <td> <%= @user.last_name %> </td>
    <td> <%= @user.email %> </td>
    <td> <%= @user.biography %> </td>
    <td> <%= @user.age %> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <%= link_to '  Edit  ', users_edit_path(id: @user.id) , class: "small button"%>
<%= link_to 'Delete     ', users_delete_path(id: @user.id),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "small button" %>
<%else%>
<h3> Such a user record does not exist. Please click on a specific user </p>
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "small button"  %>
</footer>
<%end%>
```

Can anyone help me out in using cancancan gem to restrict any user other than admin from viewing, editing, updating and deleting his own posts. Admin should be able to do these operations on everyone's records.

Please help me improve if you find me doing something wrong with the controller code too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your abilities class? you need it to prevent/white list allowable crud actions for your users.

Comment: I have same question as @BKSpurgeon. And i want to suggest to try and use the decorator( or presenter) pattern to move the logic from views into the correct decorator for each type of user . This would allow You to maintain this code easier.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following code to the initialize function of ability.rb and got it working correctly.

if user.role == "Admin"
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can [:index], User, id: user.id
      can [:show],User, id: user.id
      can [:edit],User, id: user.id
      can [:update], User,id: user.id
      can [:delete],User, id: user.id
    end